# converting list to different class structure

Tags: linq, ms-access, c#-3.0, ms-access-2007

I have a list of polylines(which i got by querying an access 2007 table) that holds the below values;

```
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| ObjectID | VertexId | distance | angle |
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|        1 |        0 |       10 |    45 |
|        1 |        1 |       10 |    44 |
|        1 |        2 |       20 |    60 |
|        2 |        0 |        5 |    35 |
|        2 |        1 |        6 |    35 |
|        2 |        2 |        4 |    56 |
|        2 |        3 |       12 |    45 |
|        3 |        0 |       20 |    30 |
|        3 |        1 |       10 |    12 |
+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

As the ObjectId column shows, there are only three objects. I would like to convert items from above list to a class in below format..

```
Class Polyline
{
    int ObjectID;
    list<int> vertices;
    list<double> distances;
    list<double> angles;
}
```

so that i can hold a List of Polyline objects and loop over each unique polyline as below..

```
foreach(Polyline polyObj in Polylines)
{
    //do something with the polyline object;

}
```

What is the best/fast way of doing this in C#? It smells Linq..i am a total newbie to linq although very eager to learn and use it..

Comment: "have a list of polyline vertices" A list of what?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - please read list of polylines..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your List of polyline is a `DataTable` that holds all values:

```
List<Polyline> polylines =
    tblPolyline.AsEnumerable()
   .GroupBy(p => p.Field<int>("ObjectID"))
   .Select(grp => new Polyline()
   {
       ObjectID = grp.Key,
       Vertices = new List<int>(grp.Select(p => p.Field<int>("VertexId"))),
       Distances = new List<double>(grp.Select(p => p.Field<double>("distance"))),
       Angles = new List<double>(grp.Select(p => p.Field<double>("angle"))),
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim..very readable and simple answer..Yes my datatable is holding the values..

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving vertices to separate class:

```
public class PolyLine
{
    public PolyLine(int id, IEnumerable<Vertex> vertices)
    {
        Id = id;
        Vertices = new List<Vertex>(vertices);
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public List<Vertex> Vertices { get; private set; }
}

public class Vertex
{
    public Vertex(int id, int distance, int angle)
    {
        Id = id;
        Distance = distance;
        Angle = angle;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int Distance { get; private set; }
    public int Angle { get; private set; }
}
```

And here is LINQ to create polylines:

```
var polylines = from r in records
                group r by r.ObjectID into g
                select new PolyLine(g.Key, g.Select(r => new Vertex(r.VertexId, r.Distance, r.Angle)));
```

UPDATE: LINQ to DataSet version

```
var polylines = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
                group r by r.Field<int>("ObjectID") into g
                select new PolyLine(g.Key, 
                             g.Select(r => new Vertex(r.Field<int>("VertexId"),
                                                      r.Field<int>("distance"), 
                                                      r.Field<int>("angle"))));
```

Comment: @vinayan good decision :) you can also use my LINQ to create polylines. I'll update answer with LINQ to dataset version